# determine SharePoint features that are actually used

Tags: sharepoint, moss

Is there a way to determine what features are actually being used by the site.
Not activated, but actually being used.

IE. FeatureA is used in /SiteA or /SiteB/Lists/ListA

I know what features are activated and have tool from codeplex to extract the deployed features as a .wsp file.

I want to cleanup the server and generate a development box from production.  Last SP admin used the production server as his play area and installed a ton of features which are not used.

Would this data be available through the SharePoint Object Model, database, or some obscure area of the site setting pages?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear from your question if you're trying to figure out which features are activated, or if you're trying to figure out which features are activated and actively used. You're using "deployed", "installed", and "activated" seemingly interchangeably in the question, and they aren't in this context.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The long answer - it really depends on the nature of the feature. Some features, such as those that add items to the menus/ribbons, are "used" only when the button is actually clicked, so the question is pretty meaningless here. If someone uses the feature button from time to time, you have no way of knowing, unless you are willing to ask everyone what they are using.